Steep missile turn during launch?
I know this might be a pretty basic and easy question, but I've started to wonder about missile aerodynamics and how they work. I recently saw a video of a Tomahawk Cruise missile launch (linked below) and I've been wondering: why does the missile, when it launches, does take such a steep turn, but takes time for the missile to accelerate and actually fly away? What is the physics behind this? Are they simple? Is there any easy way to implement this that would work efficiently and that could maybe solve some other problems I've had with steering?
This is because I've been trying to do something similar inside of my game engine!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TmhuQqPcOtY&t=50s&pp=ygUXVG9tYWhhd2sgbWlzc2lsZSBsYXVuY2g%3D

The first thing to note is that a cruise missile is actively controlling its trajectory - it is very much not like a firework rocket, where you just light the fuse and stand back.
The reason for the sharp turn after launch is that cruise missiles are designed to fly at low altitudes in order to try to evade enemy radar and anti-missile defences. The mechanism by which the turn is achieved will be a combination of automated movement of the missile's control surfaces, thrust vectoring and engine throttle control. The physics that underlies all of this is far from simple.
Attempting a realistic low-level simulation of the flight dynamics of a cruise missile (i.e. with commands to the control surfaces and engine as inputs and the missile's attitude and trajectory as output) will be a very challenging task.

Moreover, it varies from missile to missile, target location and the purpose of the project. Next to impossible to give a general explanation.

Nice example of a cold launch with pitch control: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGQ4ykokhkg&t=30s I think in the hot launch, you just can't see it: too much smoke and fire already.

This type of problem is often solved when an engineer is designing the control system for the missile.  Actual step-change tests lead to a simplified dynamic model that avoids a LOT of complicated physics equations.  In addition, any unmodeled system characteristics are dealt with by periodic feedback.

Thanks everyone! Ill try looking for an easier (and less realistic) way to implement some basic flight systems. Thanks again!
